# Как обновить ключевой столбец в android sqlite?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, autoincrement

Есть android приложение с базой данных и функцией удаления записей.
Сначала ключевые поле имеет значение: 1,2,3,4 ... потом 2,5,8 ...
Эти числа мешают навигации и через них приложение вылетает.
Можно сделать записи с PK 2,5,8 ... записями с 1,2,3,4 ...?

Comment: Как у Вас реализована навигация?

Comment: Я использую RecyclerView потом передаю позицию в запрос и получаю данные в новой Activity в которой есть ViewPager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общепринятая практика использовать первичный ключ **только** для обеспечения уникальности записи. Дополнительную функциональность лучше реализовывать через дополнительные поля